# Python heapq.heappush for tuple not working as expected

Tags: python

As the title stated, I'm a little confused on the implementation of `heapq` in python. Lets say I have an array of tuples:

```
inputArr = 
[(-8, 505),
(-9, 333), 
(-6, 2),
(-7, 94), 
(-2, 3), 
(-3, 101), 
(-4, 13), 
(-1, 5) 
(-5, 10)]
```

And I run this code:

```
arr = []
for tup in inputArr:
   heapq.heappush(arr, tup)
```

From what I understand from Python's documentation, when I use `heappush` into an array called `arr` the elements should be sorted based on the first element on the first tuple. However `arr` becomes:

`[(-9, 333), (-8, 505), (-6, 2), (-7, 94), (-2, 3), (-3, 101), (-4, 13), (-1, 5), (-5, 10)]`

As you can see, the tuples are not sorted based on the first element. I was wondering if this has something to do with the way min-heaps are structured but can't say for sure. If someone could explain this to me I'd forever be grateful.

Comment: They aren't sorted. They form a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)

Answer (score 0):

Heap only guarantees that you have a minimum element at index 0, which is true as you have -9 at 0 position (https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#module-heapq). If you want to sort array using heap, you need to pop all elements into list.

```
import heapq

inputArr = [
    (-8, 505),
    (-9, 333),
    (-6, 2),
    (-7, 94),
    (-2, 3),
    (-3, 101),
    (-4, 13),
    (-1, 5),
    (-5, 10)
]


def sort_heapq(arr):
    res = []
    heapq.heapify(inputArr)
    while len(arr) > 0:
        res.append(heapq.heappop(inputArr))
    return res

    

print(sort_heapq(inputArr))
```

Comment: _"Heap only guarantees that you have a minimum element at index 0"_, while it's true that the minimum element will be at index 0, the actual heap condition guarantees more than just that. Specifically, it guarantees that `heap[k] <= heap[2*k+1]` and `heap[k] <= heap[2*k+2]` for all `k`. That the minimum is at 0 is just a consequence of the stronger condition.